# Woocommerce save form email and cellphone on cookie and autopopulate email/cellphone on checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, hook-woocommerce

After the first product is being added to cart on Woocommerce I'm redriecting the user to a custom page with a form on it where I ask for email and cellphone.

```
FORM ID ---> #smform-28543
email ID ---> #smform-field285431
cellphone ID ---> #smform-field285432
```

The reason why I do this is because if they leave the site at least I have their data.

What I want to do is to save those 2 fields data on a cookie after they submit and then if they hit the /checkout page I want to prepopulate automatically the email and cellphone fields that is once again being asked there for billing.

An /checkout the form name is "checkout" and:

```
email ---> #billing_email
cellphone ---> #billing_phone
```

Any sample code to help me accomplish this :(

Comment: I dont know what to do honestly

Comment: here is what you need to do you need to clearly define the problem, decide if the problem can be solved easily , if it can't split the problem in more manageable problems and solve them, research each problem carefully

Comment: @madalinivascu throw a bone?

Comment: i'll trow it but can you catch it ? how about a costom page template?